# rails redirect issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to redirect depending on a value in the database.

for example if a technician is logged in they should be redirected to site A else everyone else should be redirected to site B.

my attempt so far looks as follows

```
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    @user = User.new(params[User.where(:username => @user_session.username)])
    #@user = UserUser.where(:username => @user_session.username)
    #@user = User.select("tech").find(@user)
    #@user = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save
        if @user.tech == 1
          format.html { redirect_to '/tech/index', notice: 'Login Successful A Company' }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :users, notice: @user.tech }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the if statement always resolves to the code in the else statement instead of the code above the else statement. In this case the @user.tech is nil I am somehow not pointing at the data in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

Try changing this line

```
@user = User.new(params[User.where(:username => @user_session.username)])
```

Here you do something strange, and I think you should get an error message. @user is just a new instance of the User model in memory

I think you need this

```
@user = User.where(:username => @user_session.username)]).first
```

But, if the user name is not unique, this is a security problem. A admin can have the same name as a user So you should do something like

```
@user = User.where(:id => @user_session.user_id)]).first
```

tech? method in user.rb ( the model )
I am guessing tech either 1 or 0 in the database?

```
class User
    def tech?
      tech == 1 #
    end
end
```

Now you can do

```
@user.tech?
```

And it will return ture or false

Comment: Thank you for your response Andreas,
I made the changes as you suggested however I am given the error
undefined method `tech' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3402240>
I think this was the reason I ended up instantiating a User model

Comment: add first at the end of the query. Then you'll get only one user instance, and if tech is a instance method it'll work.

Comment: tech is not a method, its a column in the database. 
however I have some good news, i got to the point that I want, now my @user.tech returns #<User tech: true> and I think the problem is now that I am asking the question " if @user.tech " and since this is the same as if #<User tech: true> it returns the error "undefined method `tech' for [#<User tech: true>]" is there a way to make @user.tech return either just true or just false?

Comment: tech is a instance method if it is a column in the database. Please have a look at the updated answer for the tech? method ( also a instance method).

Comment: ah see ok. I added the def tech? tech == 1 end into my User class, then when I am trying to use it in my session controller I get the error "undefined method `tech?' for #<Class:0x2fa6d80>"

Comment: I have made few changes to the following now
 `def self.tech?
  return true if :tech == 1
  return false if :tech == 0
 end`
this gets rid of the errors however the logic is still wrong

Comment: It should not be a class method (self.tech). here you are calling the method on one instance of the class, hence you need a instance method. Try this in the rails console. u = User.create!(:tech == 1); u.tech?, If you get the undefined method error, the either the method is not in the user model or the instance you're calling it on is not a instance of the user class

Comment: you genius, the first thing you said works, 
I dont know why it was giving me the undefined error before, but I am on a different system and its not giving that error now, your definition was enough but I forgot to mention that the data is boolean so tech == True makes the logic work properly
thank you for your patients =)